# How one can transform a statement to a system of Diophantine conditions

Tags: logic, diophantine-equations, quantifiers

It is well known that for the following statement:
$$∀y<b∃x₁,…,x_{m}[F(a,y,x₁,…,x_{m})=0]....................(1)$$
where $a$ is the parameter(s) of the polynomial $F$, the Chinese remainder theorem method results in the following system of Diophantine conditions solvable in the unknowns $q,w,z₀,…,z_{m}$ provided that (1) holds:
$$F(a,z_0,z_1,…,z_m)\equiv 0 \pmod {\binom {q}b}$$

$$z_0=q$$

$b!×( b+w+B(a,b,w))  !$ divide $q+1$

$\binom {q}b  $ divide $(\binom {z_1}w )$

$\binom {q}b  $ divide $(\binom {z_2}w )$

....

$\binom {q}b  $ divide $(\binom {z_m}w )$

where the polynomial $B(a,b,w)$ is obtained from $F(a,y,x₁,…,x_{m})$ by changing the signs of all its negative coefficients and systematically replacing $y$ by $b$ and $x₁,…,x_{m}$ by $w$.

The statement (1) is hold for all $y<b$, i.e., $0≤y<b$. Now, my question is: How one can transform the statement:

$$∀c<y<b∃x₁,…,x_{m}[F(a,y,x₁,…,x_{m})=0]....................(2)$$

to a system of Diophantine conditions where $c>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can rewrite your modified version as follows: $$\forall y<b\exists x_1,...,x_m[y=0\vee y=1\vee ... \vee y=c \vee F(a,y,x_1,...,x_m)=0].$$ Note that this **really is equivalent to** your original statement. To see this, think in terms of counterexamples (two statements are equivalent if they have the same potential counterexamples after all): a $y$ which is a counterexample to the above statement *cannot* be $\le c$ since then one of the "$y=i$"-disjuncts would automatically be true, and this corresponds to the "up front" requirement $y>c$ in your original statement.

And the above in turn can be rewritten as $$\forall y<b\exists x_1,...,x_m[G(a,y,x_1,...,x_m)=0]$$ where $G(a,y,x_1,...,x_m)=[\prod_{0\le i\le c} (y-i)]\cdot F(a,y,x_1,...,x_m)$.

Comment: But $y>c$ as an assumption.

Comment: @Safwane "$\forall c<y<b(\varphi)$" is logically equivalent to "$\forall y<b(\neg(c<y)\vee \varphi).$" And "$\neg (c<y)$" is (in this context) equivalent to "$y=0\vee y=1\vee ... \vee y=c$."

Comment: But this formulation gives a probability that $y$ equal to one of the numbers $<c$.

Comment: @Safwane Again, **that's fine**. Think in terms of counterexamples: the only way the expression I've written can be false is if there is a $y<b$ such that each of the $(y-i)$-terms is nonzero and the $F$-term is nonzero. But that's equivalent to $y<b$, $y>c$, and $F(stuff)\not=0$ which is exactly the original statement. They really are equivalent.